# Update file request results in 404

Tags: c++, google-drive-api

I'm trying to update an existing file. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload#example_resuming_an_interrupted_upload) says to use a `PUT` request with the file id and resumable as upload type.

However I'm getting a 404 with this request:

```
PUT /upload/drive/v3/files/*****?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: *****
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 20:20:08 GMT
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
Host: www.googleapis.com:443
```

See the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-GUploader-UploadID: *****
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 9
Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 20:20:07 GMT
Server: UploadServer
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
```

Changing to a `PATCH` request seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you *sure* the `[FILE_ID]` exists?  Does it contain any reserved characters that must be url-encoded in `%HH` format, and you are not doing that? Hard to know since you masked it out

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I'm pretty sure the id is valid. It was just returned from a previous list operation. Also a PATCH request with the same id gives no error. I have the impression the documentation is just incorrect.

Comment: Where did you get the file id?  Do a files.get on the file id first using the same access token this way you can be sure that the file actually exists for this user.

Comment: @DaImTo the id was returned from a previous list operation in the same session. I'm pretty sure the id is ok otherwise the PATCH request would have also failed.

Answer (score 2):

Could be wrong fileId as Remy suggests. Also could be a session expiry.

Or, could be a documentation error. The page you linked to says use PUT, but the reference page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update says use PATCH